# How does SQL decide to add new data page

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to understand how SQL allots a new data pages as when we insert some new records into a table.

I have create a sample table called Employee in a fresh database by -

```
Create Database TestDb
GO
Use TestDb
GO
Create table Employee (
EmployeeName char(1000))   GO
Insert into Employee values ('Employee1')

DBCC IND('TestDb','dbo.Employee',-1)
```

After running DBCC, I saw 2 pages. One was IAM page (PageType =10 ) and other was Data Page (PageType = 1) which holds actual data.

Later I verified the actual content of data page by using DBCC Page

```
DBCC TRACEON(3604)
DBCC PAGE('TestDb',1,298,3)
```

I saw how SQL calculated the m_freecnt bytes count -

= 1007 bytes RecordSize + 96 bytes Header + 2 bytes offset =  1105 Bytes

i.e. 8K Page = 8192 bytes  = 8192 - 1105 = **7087  Bytes Free.**

[image]

Now I go on adding records to this table in order to understand how many records this page will accommodate and when SQL will allot a new page keeping m_FreeCnt in mind.

> *(Record Size = 1007 & Offset Bytes = 2 )*

Added 2nd record -

```
Insert into Employee values ('Employee2') GO
```

Last Free Count = 7087 i.e. 7087 - 1007 - 2 = 6087 => m_FreeCnt = 6078

```
Insert into Employee values ('Employee3') GO
```

Last Free Count = 6078 i.e. 6078 - 1007 - 2 = 5069 => m_FreeCnt = 5069

```
Insert into Employee values ('Employee4') GO
```

Last Free Count = 5069 i.e. 5069 - 1007 - 2 = 4060 => m_FreeCnt = 4060

```
Insert into Employee values ('Employee5') GO
```

Last Free Count = 4060 i.e. 4060 - 1007 - 2 = 3051 => m_FreeCnt = 3051

```
Insert into Employee values ('Employee6') GO
```

Last Free Count = 3051 i.e. 3051 - 1007 - 2 = 2042 => m_FreeCnt = 2042

```
Insert into Employee values ('Employee7') GO
```

Last Free Count = 2042 i.e. 2042 - 1007 - 2 = 1033 => m_FreeCnt = 1033

Till now everything works normal. Now we have 1033 bytes left in this data page. As soon as I add 8th record, ideally it should not create another page because the number of bytes free are **1033** bytes which is sufficient enough to accommodate 8th record (1009 bytes are enough). However, SQL does create a new Date page to save this 8th record.

I inserted 8th record and ran DBCC IND to check this -

```
Insert into Employee values ('Employee7') GO

DBCC IND('TestDb','dbo.Employee',-1)
```

Now it has created a new Data Page with PageNumber = 300.

I did not understand this part. Whether SQL keeps some bytes reserved except [header (96) + Data part + offset per page 2 bytes] this?

You can try running above queries and let me know If I am missing out anything here? Or whether we shouldn't bother about these memory details of SQL?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just re-phrase another answer to make it clear:
As soon as you reach 81% of your page filled, PFS record for that page will change first 2 bits to be `11`, which will mean that "Page is 95% full" and SQL Will not allow inserting any more records even though there is plenty of space (more than 5% are free).

There are two ways to fight that problem:
Easy: Create clustered index - then you will be able to set fillfactor as 100% if needed.
Difficult: If you have on your page more than 19% of free space you can insert more than one record using ONE `INSERT` statement to fill the page 100%.
See example:

```
CREATE TABLE TestTable(F0 SMALLINT);
GO
INSERT INTO TestTable (F0) 
SELECT TOP 699 1 FROM sys.messages;
GO
BEGIN TRAN 
  INSERT INTO TestTable (F0) 
  SELECT TOP 37 2 FROM sys.messages;
  SELECT 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sys.dm_db_database_page_allocations(DB_ID(), OBJECT_ID('TestTable'), NULL, NULL, 'DETAILED') WHERE Page_type = 1) AS Pages,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TestTable) AS "Count";
ROLLBACK
GO
BEGIN TRAN 
  INSERT INTO TestTable (F0) VALUES (3)
  GO 2
  SELECT 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sys.dm_db_database_page_allocations(DB_ID(), OBJECT_ID('TestTable'), NULL, NULL, 'DETAILED') WHERE Page_type = 1) AS Pages,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TestTable) AS "Count";
ROLLBACK
GO
DROP TABLE TestTable
GO
```

After you reach 699 records you can insert 37 new records at once or only one record if you insert on record-by-record basis.

Comment: Hi Slava, Creating a Clustered Index works like a charm. I modified the schema to add a primary key column and then the entire memory bytes were got used. NO wastage of memory. Many Thanks  :)

Comment: Be careful. Use 100% fillfactor only when your clustered index column is sequential to avoid any Page Splits.

Answer (score 0):

That is what I found : http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/21877.sql-server-how-does-sql-server-allocate-space-in-a-heap.aspx

> In total there are 2 records stored on the data page (m_slotCnt) and
>   the page has 3,063 bytes available for new records (m_freeCnt). If
>   Microsoft SQL Server will insert a new record into this page, it has
>   to be inserted at the offset 5,126 (m_freeData). Last but not least
>   the page is used by 51% - 80%. If Microsoft SQL Server would read the
>   information from the page header it should be aware of the 3,062 bytes
>   available space on the page. But it doesn't!
>
> The record 3 has a length of 2504 bytes + row overhead but Microsoft
>   SQL Server has not inserted the record on the page 150 because of the
>   following calculation:
>
> The PFS reports a space usage of 80% which mean 6,554 bytes from the
>   complete page space. The free space of the page is 1,638 bytes and the
>   record 3 has a length of 2,504 bytes which does not fit to the page
>   based on these calculation! This calculation is manifesting the PFS
>   scan instead of a dedicated scan of the page header. Because the new
>   record does not fit on the page a new one will be created as the
>   extract from the transaction log will make visible.

For your example:

```
m_slotCnt   7
m_freeCnt   1033
m_freeData  7145
PFS (1:1)   0x63 MIXED_EXT ALLOCATED  95_PCT_FULL
```

8192*0.95=7782

8192-7782=409 <1007

I've repeated your example with row length = 10 char (107 bytes) and what I get:

```
m_freeCnt   357
PFS (1:1)   0x64 MIXED_EXT ALLOCATED 100_PCT_FULL
```

real PFS =  95.6%, but SQL Engine count it like 100_PCT_FULL and create new page for next row